# How can a class reference itself through `std::array<>` iterators in C++?

Tags: c++, iterator, shared-ptr, self-reference, stdarray

The following class would not compile because it has an incomplete type for self-reference.

```cpp
class SelfRef{
  using DependencyReference = std::array<SelfRef, 10>::const_iterator;
public:
  std::array<DependencyReference, 3> dependencies;
};

std::array<SelfRef, 1000> operationArray;
```

What is suprising for me is that full type definition is required even though the Self-reference is supposed to be through iterators. Is there a way to use iterators here, or the only way to store the self-reference is through pointers?

In case pointers are the only possible solution for this problem, is it safe to use `std::shared_ptr` here? I would think that it isn't because the pointer does not have ownership-

But using `const SelfRef*` seems pretty error-prone..

Comment: why do you consider a non-owning `SelfRef*` error-prone? When no ownership is involved, smart pointers arent "safer"

Comment: Even if you worked around the incomplete type, isn't `std::array<SelfRef, 10>::const_iterator; std::array<SelfRef, 1000> operationArray;` suspicious? (they are probably SCARY iterators tho)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number my primary concern is  checking for validity, which is at least more delegated to the standard with [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool). Of course what 'seems' error-prone to me can be made stable with e.g. best practice suggestions.

Comment: _"...I would think that it isn't because the pointer does not have ownership....."_ have the owner hold a `std::shared_ptr` and give out `std::weak_ptr`s to observer objects.  This is safer than using raw pointers for observers as you can test if the owner has deleted the managed object.  Only if the life-time of the managed (observed) object can be guaranteed to outlast the life-time of any observers then using raw pointers for the observers is ok.

Comment: @DávidTóth `SelfRef` must be defined when you declare an alias for `const_iterator` for the same reason that any class must be defined when trying to apply increment `++` operation to the pointer to an object of this class. The compiler needs to know how many bytes to move the pointer. Try this example: `class A; A* obj; ++obj;` You will get a warning that the pointer to an incomplete type cannot be incremented.